# Stylesheet border effects not showing up when applied in object constructor

Tags: qt, qlabel

I'm trying to apply a stylesheet to my subclass of QLabel in it's constructor. I can affect the text, but my attempts to mess with the border have failed.

In MyLabel constructor:

```
setStyleSheet("border-color : red"
              "border-style : solid"
              "border-width : thick");
```

Yet no border appears...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the width in pixel. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#border-width-prop

Comment: Mmm, thanks. Looks like I need semicolons after each specification as well.